# CTE to replace JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Can I use CTE instead of the my code here  ? Here are the two tables and my code .

```
tbl1

D_ID    department      employee name            manager name
112         d01         john d                   Peter k
113         d01         Emily f                  kevin s 

tbl2 

Emp_id   employee name    D_ID  
100      john d           112 
200      peter k          112
800      Emily f          113
500      kevin s          113
```

My code below  , what I did is I joined tbl1 with tbl2 on D_ID and employee name and then filter out the records where employee's emp_id > manager's emp_id .

```
DECLARE @level nvarchar(MAX) =
(
     select X.D_ID ,x.employee_NAME, x.emp_ID as employee_id, 
         y.manager_name ,y.emp_id as manager_id
) + ' '
from (
    select distinct b.d_id , a.emp_id as employee_id 
    from tbl1  a , tbl2 b 
    where a.d_id=b.d_id and a.employee_NAME=b.employee_NAME
) x ,
(
    select distinct b.d_id , a.emp_id as manager_id
    from tbl1  a , tbl2 b 
    where a.d_id=b.d_id and a.employee_NAME=b.manager_NAME
) Y
where x.department=y.department and x.employee_id>=y.manager_id

FOR XML PATH('')
)
IF @level IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR(' employee ID>manager_id:  %s',16, 1, @level) 
            with log;
        END;
```

DESIRED OUTPUT is below as Emily f's employee id is > than her manager's ID .

```
 D_ID  employee_NAME  employee_id manager_name  manager_id 
 113   Emily f         800        kevin s       500
```

Comment: Plz add your desired O/P

Comment: Please see desired output added above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need some joins:

```
select t1.d_id, t1.employee_name, te.emp_id,
       t1.employee_name as manager_name, tm.emp_id as manager_id
from tbl1 t1 join
     tbl2 te
     on t1.employee_name = te.employee_name join
     tbl2 tm
     on t1.manager_name = tm.employee_name
where te.emp_id > tm.emp_id;
```

It is quite curious that you are using the names to connect the two tables.  Normally, you would use the employee id for this purpose and look up the name using the id.

Comment: I know what you mean but this is how the tables are setup currently  . I thought CTE is better performance wise than JOINS therefore wanted to use CTE .

Comment: @user3844877 . . . You are misguided.  CTEs are a shorthand for subqueries.  They use the same underlying methods for doing joins and groups by as regular queries.  Databases are usually optimized to do joins efficiently.

Comment: the table is set up with the ids, it is likely faster and more accurate to use them. THe problem with joining on names and why you should NEVER  do it is that more than one person can have the same name, yes even in the same company (I have worked in at least three companies where this was true and handle data from hundreds of companies where this is true)! You hire that second person with the same name and all your code breaks. very poor idea.